# Preserve Indentation w/ Output in Blade Template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this stored in database:

```
<p>Toast with jelly.</p>
<div>
  here is a div
  <div>
    that is nested nicely
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this in my blade template:

```
{!! nl2br(e($pattern->code)) !!}
```

Which allows me to maintain my line breaks and show code. But the indentation white space is not preserved.

```
<p>Toast with jelly.</p>
<div>
here is a div
<div>
that is nested nicely
</div>
</div>
```

With twig in symfony that type of thing was preserved with `variable|raw`. But I can't seem to figure out how to do this with Blade.

Anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to render the HTML to the browser to view the tags and everything. Correct me on that if I am wrong, please.

Try wrapping the output in a `<pre>` tag ([docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)), which will honor the blank spaces. You won't need to do `nl2br()` anymore either since it honors line endings as well. Also, be careful of spacing here too because if you add spaces around the `{!! !!}` tag you may get a result that you don't want.

```
<pre>{!! e($pattern->code) !!}</pre>
```

Yields the following for me in Firefox:

```
<p>Toast with jelly.</p>
<div>
  here is a div
  <div>
    that is nested nicely
  </div>
</div>
```